# Login prompt remains displayed after login

Tags: login, desktop-background

[The LOGIN Pannel freezes....Unable to change Wallpaper](http://postimg.org/image/o0ml8fpsx/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choose "Advanced" option from the GRUB menu and try another kernel version to login...
The GRUB: The first screen while opening the computer. It's headline is GNU GRUB. There is an opton in that menu. You can make it visible with pressing and holding the Shift key at boot time.

Comment: what is GRUB menu and how to try another kernel version to login .... i'm very new to linux(ubuntu).